# Need help to get drop down in a list (phpunit+selenium2)

Tags: selenium2, phpunit

I am new in Phpunit and selenium2.

Need help to get all the values of drop-down in a list.

```
<select id="month" class="_5dba" title="Month" name="birthday_month" aria-label="Month">
  <option selected="1" value="0">Month</option>
  <option value="1">Jan</option>
  <option value="2">Feb</option>
  <option value="3">Mar</option>
  <option value="4">Apr</option>
  <option value="5">May</option>
  <option value="6">Jun</option>
  <option value="7">Jul</option>
  <option value="8">Aug</option>
  <option value="9">Sep</option>
  <option value="10">Oct</option>
  <option value="11">Nov</option>
  <option value="12">Dec</option>
</select>
```

so, values that should be in the list are : jan, feb, .....

Comment: I am trying to do this as well, but first I would like to count the selections, and if possible return the results. For testing purposes I feel it would be best to allow for changes made in large dropdown lists by simply counting and returning all the possible values (then I can select one randomly). It seems odd that I cannot find any methods for doing this.

Answer (score 1):

This is the way as per the [link](http://release.seleniumhq.org/selenium-core/1.0/reference.html)

```
$this->select($this->byId('month'))->selectOptionByValue(2);
```

OR

```
$this->select("month", "label=Option label");
$this->select("month", "value=Option value"); 
$this->select("month", "id=Option id"); 
$this->select("month", "index=Option index");
```

Answer (score 1):

**I see 2 ways:**

$options = array('1', '2', '3', '4', '5', '6', '7', '8', '9', '10', '11', '12');

foreach ($options as $option) {

```
$this->select($this->byId("month"))->selectOptionByValue($option);
```

}

OR:

for ($i = 0; $i < 12; $i++ ) {

```
$this->select($this->byId("month"))->selectOptionByValue($i);
```

}